# GUIDE4YOU - how to add an ArcGIS REST Feature Service layer

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, guide4you

I was wondering if Guide4You supports adding an ArcGIS REST Feature Service layer?

For example the official Openlayers example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html

I hope someone can help me out!

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an empty feature source in the layer config and then replace the source with the code provided in the openlayers example.

layerconfig for empty layer:

```
{
  "id": "someId",
  "title": "someTitle",
  "type": "Intern",
  "source": {}
}
```

and then just get the layer with `map.getLayerGroup().getLayerById("someId")`and replace the source